# Append text to file and print it's contents to console simultaneously?

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

I've spent over an hour on this, and i just can't get any text to show up in the .txt file. What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class writer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File txt = new File("myTextFile.txt");
        FileWriter fw = null;
        fw = new FileWriter(txt);
        BufferedWriter edit = null;
        edit = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String s = "more text", line = null;
        edit.write(s);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(txt);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String i = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Edit: Added a **.write**, but it's still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never close the `BufferedWriter` instance and you never flush it either.       So you never leave a change the buffer of the stream to be effectively written in the physical file.
Actually you read the file from the same source that you use just before to write in.  So you have to explicitly flush the buffer of `BufferedWriter` before reading the content with the `Scanner` :

```
BufferedWriter edit = new BufferedWriter(fw);
String s = "more text", line = null;
edit.write(s);
edit.flush(); // modification here
Scanner sc = new Scanner(txt);
```